# How to Play music in my ios application from a link ( soundcloud )

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, soundcloud

The below is the link where I uploaded my song file "https://soundcloud.com/smkumar84/summa". From here I need to play the music in my iphone application.

How can I do it in my iphone app?

Comment: what have you tried? it's good to show what effort you've made to find a solution prior to asking others for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [api for ios from soundcloud.](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/ios-quickstart) and [Apple's Guide on HTTP streaming](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

The soundcloud API supports

1. Getting list of sounds
2. Playing Sounds
3. Uploading Sounds

The Apple's example on HTTP live streaming can be utilizes to stream Audio & Video over HTTP. This is also applicable for an ordinary server without much setup.

Comment: The link for soundcloud ios seems obsolete

Answer (score 0):

You can use AVPlayer/AVAudioPlayer for playing songs. 
Check AVAudioPlayer API's.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer